# Generate and store todays date + 11 months, and + 1 year

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to generate a number of dates in php that are then stored in a MySQL db.

Todays date, Todays date + 1 yr, Todays date +11 Months, Todays date + 364 days

ie: 12 Sep 2013, 12 Sep 2014, 12 Aug  2014, 11 Sep 2014

What is the best way to go about this?

I can get todays date from:

```
function zen_date_created_stat($raw_date) {
    if ($raw_date == '') return false;
    $year = substr($raw_date, 2, 2);
    $month = (int)substr($raw_date, 4, 2);
    $day = (int)substr($raw_date, 6, 2);
    return date(DATE_FORMAT, mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
}
$date_installed = date("d M y");
```

So far I've failed to get the other dates, just a bunch of errors.

Comment: I'd suggest doing date arithmetic in your queries.  Look in the MySQL manual for "date arithmetic" rather than messing with it in PHP.

Comment: `What is the best way to go about this?` Simple. Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). From the examples:

```
<?php
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
?>
```

Comment: -1 variables as provided are UNIX Timestamps (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC) not Dates.  To convert from timestamp to date, use the DATE function.  (ex. date("m/d/Y", $today); )

Comment: @Lumberjack - That's being pedantic to say the least. The OP obviously has a grasp of how to convert the required values to a valid format he can use, he merely needed to know how to get that data in the first place which most of the answers provide a solution to.

Comment: @Glavić - There is no doubt in my mind that you know the answer to that so I would suggest that if you don't have an answer, don't troll.

Comment: Only one here trolling are you guys, that don't close this question as duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

The two common ways to modify dates in PHP:

- Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) with [relative formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).
- Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and its [`add()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) or [`modify()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method.

**Note:** This answer is intentionally general to promote awareness and RTM.

Comment: +1 `Note: This answer is intentionally generally to promote awareness and RTFM.` I think we all had the same though there ;)

Comment: @webnoob, had to add the disclaimer for the trolling down voters. :) Really though, I see questions on date manipulation all the time. Sooner or later, I'm going to make one answer to rule them all.

Answer (score 1):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) is probably your best bet:

```
$today = strtotime("now");
$next_year = strtotime("+1 year");
$eleven_months = strtotime("+11 months");
$many_days = strtotime("+364 days");
// personally I'd recommend "+1 year -1 day" to account for leap years
```

Comment: -1 variables as provided are UNIX Timestamps (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC) not Dates.  To convert from timestamp to date, use the DATE function.  (ex. date("m/d/Y", $today); )

Comment: @Lumberjack Considering OP is already using `date` to convert the timestamp given by `mktime`, I sort of assumed they'd know how to use it on `strtotime`...

Comment: @Kolink: this is not the best bet, best bet would be using `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

`strtotime()` takes two arguments.  The first argument is a string indicating the date or operation (ex. +11 months).  The second is optional and indicates the base timestamp on which to perform the operation.  If you don't provide a second argument, the function uses NOW as the default time.

```
<?php
   $todays_date = strtotime("today");
   $tomorrows_date = strtotime("+1 day"); 
   $delta_eleven = strtotime("+11 months");
   $delta_year = strtotime("+1 year");
   $delta_364 = strtotime("+364 days");

   //the values you have above are TIMESTAMPS (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC)
   //if you want dates, you can convert as follows

   $today = date("m/d/Y", $todays_date);
   $tomorrow = date("m/d/Y", $tomorrows_date);
   $plus_eleven = date("m/d/Y", $delta_eleven);
   $plus_year = date("m/d/Y", $delta_year);
   $plus_364 = date("m/d/Y", $delta_364);

   echo $today . " " . $tomorrow . " " . $plus_eleven . " " . $plus_year . " " . $plus_364;
?>
```

Comment: You've do realize you trolled everyone else's answer, only to leave the same one (with use of `date()`) 16 minutes after everyone else.

Comment: @Jason McCreary - OP asked for a Date, not a Timestamp.  I did not point out the shortcomings of the other answers in order to elicit an emotional response from the other people who answered, but rather to promote an accurate and complete answer.  If my doing so upset you, I apologize.

Comment: @Glavic The integer result from +60 years exceeds the max value for an integer.  Try ` echo strtotime("+ 24 years"); echo strtotime("+25 years");` The first will work the second will not.

Comment: OP didn't ask to add 60 years, he wants to add 1 year, but I get your point.  One could argue however that not all applications need to be written with a 35 year life cycle in mind.

Comment: I could say `If as you say the two answers are identical, then strtotime() is best because it requires less keystrokes to code.` but that would just by my pathetic attempt to win a pointless argument with a complete stranger.  Instead I will say the truth: I said it was "The Best" because it was the answer that I was most familiar with.  I am not nearly as comfortable with DateTime (personally) as I am with strtotime().  I find strtotime() to be simple and easy to understand, whereas even after reading the DateTime:Add documentation, I would still need more information before I could answer OP

Comment: I will adjust me answer to remove the assertion that strtotime is `best.`